# How to repeate the process and store result in the new data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, geopandas

I have 2 datasets `border` and `df`.

## PART 1:

```
df = 

     id_easy    ordinal latitude longitude      epoch   day_of_week
0   e35f652a         68  22.1111    7.2222 1465084811   Sunday
1   e35f652a         69  22.1111    7.2222 1465084870   Sunday
2   e35f652a         70  22.1111    7.2222 1465084930   Sunday
3   e35f652a         71  22.1111    7.2222 1465084990   Sunday
4   e35f652a         72  22.1111    7.2222 1465085050   Sunday

turin = df.loc[df['ordinal'] == 1]

crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(turin.longitude,turin.latitude)]
turin_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(turin,crs=crs,geometry=geometry) #to get geometry
```

---

## PART 2:

`border.shape` = `(931, 674)`
first number in column names shows the zone name. For example, in `12_longitude_1` = zone 12, longitude, 1-st. I have random zones as you can see (12,14,23... and so on)

Here is sample data frame:

```
border = 

12_longitude_1  12_latitude_1   14_longitude_2  14_latitude_2   23_longitude_3  23_latitude_3
            11             12               13             14               15            16
            11             12               13             14               15            16
            11             12               13             14               15            16
```

---

## FINAL PART:

I want to check `turin_point` within the zone `12`.
I am doing the following operation with first 2 columns:

Code for `12_longitude_1`,`12_latitude_1`:

```
border = border[['longitude_1','latitude_1']].dropna()
border.longitude_1 = border.longitude_1.replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
border.latitude_1 = border.latitude_1.replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
border.longitude_1 = pd.to_numeric(border.longitude_1, errors='coerce')
border.latitude_1 = pd.to_numeric(border.latitude_1, errors='coerce')
geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border.longitude_1,border.latitude_1)]
border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
long_lat_1 = len(within_turin)
```

Finally `long_lat_12` gives me `1697`

---

I want to automate this process for the whole dataset (for all column couples)?

---

## Desired output:

[image]

Libraries to use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
```

---

## TRY:

```
pd_out = pd.DataFrame({'zone': [], 'number': []})

for col_num in range(0, len(border.columns)-1, 2):
    curr_lon_name = border.columns[col_num]
    curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1]
    num = curr_lon_name.split("_")[-1]
    border = border[[curr_lon_name, curr_lat_name]].dropna()
    border[curr_lon_name] = border[curr_lon_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lat_name] = border[curr_lat_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lon_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lon_name], errors='coerce')
    border[curr_lat_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lat_name], errors='coerce')
    geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border[curr_lon_name],border[curr_lat_name])]
    border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
    turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
    within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
    curr_len = len(within_turin)
    pd_out = pd_out.append({'zone': "long_lat_{}".format(num), 'number': curr_len}, ignore_index=True)
```

Gives me only 1 row:

```
    zone         number
0   long_lat_1  1697.0
```

I want all rows and names as indicated in the photo

p.s. values of data sets were changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the border dataframe in your for loop. Make a series from border dataframe instead or overwriting it:

```py
pd_out = pd.DataFrame({'zone': [], 'number': []})

for col_num in range(0, len(border.columns)-1, 2):
    curr_lon_name = border.columns[col_num]
    curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1]
    num = curr_lon_name.split("_")[0]
    zone_border = border[[curr_lon_name, curr_lat_name]].dropna()
    zone_border[curr_lon_name] = zone_border[curr_lon_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    zone_border[curr_lat_name] = zone_border[curr_lat_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    zone_border[curr_lon_name] = pd.to_numeric(zone_border[curr_lon_name], errors='coerce')
    zone_border[curr_lat_name] = pd.to_numeric(zone_border[curr_lat_name], errors='coerce')
    geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(zone_border[curr_lon_name],zone_border[curr_lat_name])]
    border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(zone_border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
    turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
    within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
    curr_len = len(within_turin)
    pd_out = pd_out.append({'zone': "{}".format(num), 'number': curr_len}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Issue 1: in column `pd_out` I get `0` everywhere except 1 cell. But I should get a number more than `0`

Comment: @Mamed It looks like *turin_final* is a polygon made up of the zone numbers in the *border*  dataframe. For example:

`print(turin_final.wkt)
POLYGON ((11 12, 11 12, 11 12, 11 12))`

This is creating a polygon that is really a point at 11,12.

turin_point will not be within that kind of polygon. See [GeoSeries.within(self, other)](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.within).

Comment: @Mamed correction: I realized that the values in _border_ are coordinates, and not zone numbers. They will still need to include a set of coordinates to make a valid polygon, in order to check if the turin_point's are within those polygons.

Comment: @Mamed I updated the code to remove the comments I previously made, and replace `border = border` with `zone_border = border` etc. I think this helps solve why you were only getting 1 row.  I am wondering now if it is the data in _border_ that is the new issue. Do you have a more complete example of the border dataframe to test?

Comment: I just restarted the Kernel and it works. Let me double check and I will accept the answer